# what happens with the child branches if a rebase a parent branch but not the child?

Tags: git, rebase

Let's say I have the following

```
 ------------------Dev
     \   
     Branch1------------------Branch2
            \-----Branch3
```

and I want to have the features of `Branch1` in `Dev` so I checkout to `Branch1` and I do `git rebase Dev`.

I expect to have the branch `Branch1` moved to the top of `Dev` but what happens to `Branch2` and `Branch3`?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing happens to `Branch2` and `Branch3`, which will remain as they are, the same history.  Here are more detailed before and after graphs.  Here is the before:

```
Dev:      A -- B
           \
Branch1:    C -- D
             \    \
Branch3:      \    F
Branch2:       E
```

And here is the after, once you have run `git rebase dev` from `Branch1`:

```
Branch1:         C' -- D'   (after rebase)
                /
Dev:      A -- B
           \
            C -- D   <-- most likely no branch has a HEAD pointing here at this point
             \    \
Branch3:      \    F
Branch2:       E
```

The same history should be present for the other two branches, as rebasing only rewrites history for the target branch which you mention.

Comment: so you are saying that in this case reabase instead of *moving* the branch, actually makes a copy of it? (in this case C'--D')?

Comment: Not exactly, it doesn't "move" the branch either.  The commits `C'` and `D'` you see above are actually completely _new_ commits.  Rebasing in this case literally writes out a new `Branch1`.  That being said, the old commits are still there, and in fact are part of the history of the `Branch2` and `Branch3` branches, so, that part of the diagram would just remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

A branch is attached to a commit.

`git checkout Branch1 && git rebase Dev` is equivalent to `git rebase Dev Branch1`.

First, it finds out the commits that are reachable from `Branch1` and new to `Dev`.

Then, it applies these commits onto `Dev` one by one. Empty commits may be ignored.

Finally, it moves `Branch1` to the last new commit.

In the process, `Branch2` and `Branch3` stay where they are.

Here are the graphs before and after. The images are from [learninggitbranch](https://learngitbranching.js.org/?NODEMO).

Before,

[image]

After,

[image]

Ignore `master` on the graph. It's not allowed to delete `master` in this app. `C3` is the commit that's reachable from `Branch1` and new to `Dev`. It's applied onto `Dev` and `C3'` is created. `Branch1` is moved to `C3'`. `C3` and other commits are unchanged, so are `Branch2` and `Branch3`.

Commands to reproduce the process on learninggitbranch,

```
git checkout -b Dev
git commit
git checkout -b Branch1 C1
git commit
git checkout -b Branch2
git commit
git checkout -b Branch3 C3
git commit
git checkout Branch2
git commit
git rebase Dev Branch1
```